# KendoUI Pie Chart not Working

Tags: json, charts, kendo-ui

I cannot get this simple KendoUI Pie chart to work and I do not see anything wrong with the code.

I only have some basic JSON which I am trying to bind to. As you can see the source data contains already calculated percentages and also the actual values. I am only trying to bind the pie chart to the percentage columns. The reason for the percentageUnit and percentageValue is because I already have code in place to switch between the two. The actual value and unit fields will be used as tooltips. So it is important to have all that data in the source.

The chart does populate but looks totally messed up. Is it me or Kendo?

http://jsfiddle.net/jqIndy/38gH4/

[image: Pie Chart Result]

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>JS Bin</title>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2012.3.1114/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
  <link href="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2012.3.1114/styles/kendo.common.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <link href="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2012.3.1114/styles/kendo.default.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <link href="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2012.3.1114/styles/kendo.dataviz.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <link href="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2012.3.1114/styles/kendo.dataviz.default.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body>
  <div id="client-order-status"></div>

  <script>
    var dr = [{
        Status: "CANCELLED",
        Units:554615.000000000000,
        Value:12194910.410000000000,
        PercentageUnits:12.955700000000,
        PercentageValue:25.479241000000
      },{
        Status: "INVOICED",
        Units:3260369.000000000000,
        Value:31610141.095120000000,
        PercentageUnits:76.161596000000,
        PercentageValue:66.044143000000
      },{
        Status: "OPEN",
        Units: 465873.000000000000,
        Value: 4057089.598000000000,
        PercentageUnits: 10.882704000000,
        PercentageValue: 8.476615000000
      }];

      var dsCOStatus = new kendo.data.DataSource({
        data: dr,
        schema: {
          type: "json",
          model: {
            fields: {
              Status: "Status",
              PercentageUnits: "PercentageUnits",
              PercentageValue: "PercentageValue",
              Units: "Units",
              Value: "Value"
            }
          }
        },
      });

      $(function () {

        $("#client-order-status").kendoChart({
          dataSource: dsCOStatus,
          title: {
            text: "Client Order Status (past 12 months)"
          },
          legend: {
            position: "bottom"
            //labels: {
            //  template: "#= text # (#= value #%)"
            //}
          },
          seriesDefaults: {
            type: "pie"
            //labels: {
            //  visible: true,
            //  format: "{0}%"
            //}
          },
          series: [{
            field: "Status",
            categoryField: "Value"
          }],
          tooltip: {
            visible: true
            //format: "{0}"
          }
        }).show();
      });

  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

In XML I have the same problem:

```
var drXML = "<D><Report><Status>CANCELLED</Status><Units>554615.000000000000</Units><Value>12194910.410000000000</Value><PercentageUnits>12.955700000000</PercentageUnits><PercentageValue>25.479241000000</PercentageValue></Report><Report><Status>INVOICED</Status><Units>3260369.000000000000</Units><Value>31610141.095120000000</Value><PercentageUnits>76.161596000000</PercentageUnits><PercentageValue>66.044143000000</PercentageValue></Report><Report><Status>OPEN</Status><Units>465873.000000000000</Units><Value>4057089.598000000000</Value><PercentageUnits>10.882704000000</PercentageUnits><PercentageValue>8.476615000000</PercentageValue></Report></D>";

    var dsCOStatus = new kendo.data.DataSource({
      data: drXML,
      schema: {
        type: "xml",
        data: "/D/Report",
        model: {
          fields: {
            Status: "Status/text()",
            PercentageUnits: "PercentageUnits/text()",
            PercentageValue: "PercentageValue/text()",
            Units: "Units/text()",
            Value: "Value/text()"
          }
        }
      }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you need to swap your categoryField and field names:

```
series: [{
    field: "Value",
    categoryField: "Status"
}]
```

From the [API reference](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/dataviz/chart):

- **categoryField**: The data field containing the sector category name.
- **valueField**: The data field containing the series value.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It works fine for JSON but if I doe the same with XML it still does the same. Any ideas? Have a look at my datasource code above for XML. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer. Because XML is being returned/parsed as text it seems that the KendoUI grid does not accept this as a valid value. After changing the value field it works fine.

See this URL:

http://www.kendoui.com/forums/ui/grid/sort-order-numeric-with-xml-binded-datasource.aspx

Thanks Gudman!

Answer below:

```
 schema: {
        type: "xml",
        data: "/DsCOStatus/Report",
        model: {
          fields: {
            Status: "Status/text()",
            PercentageUnits: "PercentageUnits/text()",
            PercentageValue: "PercentageValue/text()",
            Units: "Units/text()",
            Value: { field: "Value/text()", type:"number" }
            //Value: "Value/text()"
          }
        }
      }
```